# How to read Armenian texts from Laravel MSSQL database

Tags: php, sql-server, laravel

When I connect to MSSQL database in Laravel framework and read data from any table, I get something like this:

> "Ü»ñÏ»ñ ¨ Ý»ñÏ³ÝÛáõÃ»ñ           "

I store Armenian texts in my database. I've tried to use many different charsets, but I still can't solve my issue.

What type of charsets should I use?

Data stored in varchar.
I'm use current coonfiguration for connection:

```
'sqlsrv' => [
            'driver' => 'sqlsrv',
            'host' => env('MS_DB_HOST', 'localhost'),
            'port' => env('MS_DB_PORT', '1433'),
            'database' => env('MS_DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
            'username' => env('MS_DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
            'password' => env('MS_DB_PASSWORD', ''),
            'charset' => 'utf8',
            'collation' => 'utf8_bin',
            'prefix' => ''
        ],
```

@@version of sql database:
Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 (SP1) - 10.50.2500.0 (X64) 
    Jun 17 2011 00:54:03 
    Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation
    Standard Edition (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.1  (Build 7601: Service Pack 1)

[Table screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wpf6T.png)

```
select c.name, t.name, c.collation_name from sys.columns c join sys.types t on c.system_type_id = t.system_type_id where object_id = object_id('VMATERIALS')
```

And

```
select c.name, t.name, c.collation_name from test.sys.columns c join sys.types t on c.system_type_id = t.system_type_id where object_id = object_id('VMATERIALS')
```

[Query result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UHb7F.png)

In my MSSQL database I have procedure:

```
CREATE FUNCTION asf_ConvertANSIToUnicode (@Source varchar(500)) RETURNS nvarchar(500) AS
BEGIN
DECLARE @Result nvarchar(500)
DECLARE @i bigint
DECLARE @CharCode bigint
DECLARE @Diff bigint
SET @i = 1
SET @Result = ''
While @i <= LEN(@Source)
      Begin
        SET @CharCode = ASCII(SUBSTRING(@Source,@i,1))
        IF @CharCode<128
           SET @CharCode = @CharCode
        ELSE
            IF @CharCode between 178 and 253
                  begin
                        SET @Diff = @CharCode - 178
                        IF @CharCode % 2 = 0
                           SET @CharCode = 1329 + @Diff / 2
                        ELSE
                           SET @CharCode = 1377 + (@Diff-1) / 2
                  END
            ELSE 
                  SET @CharCode = CASE @CharCode
                                        When 162 Then 1415
                                        When 163 Then 1417
                                        When 164 Then 41
                                        When 165 Then 40
                                        When 166 Then 187
                                        When 167 Then 171
                                        When 168 Then 8212
                                        When 169 Then 46
                                        When 170 Then 1373
                                        When 171 Then 44
                                        When 172 Then 45
                                        When 173 Then 1418
                                        When 174 Then 8230
                                        When 175 Then 1372
                                        When 176 Then 1371
                                        When 177 Then 1374
                                        When 254 Then 1370
                                        ELSE @CharCode
                                   END
        SET @Result = @Result + nchar(@CharCode)
        SET  @i = @i + 1
      END 
RETURN @Result
END
```

And

```
CREATE FUNCTION asfe_ConvertANSIToUnicode (@Source varchar(500)) RETURNS nvarchar(500) AS
BEGIN
    RETURN dbo.asf_ConvertANSIToUnicode (@Source)
END
```

If it can help my, how I can use it in query?

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/185232/discussion-on-question-by-vardan-nersesyan-how-to-read-armenian-texts-from-larav).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my case in my database I have function for converting ansi to unicode:

```
CREATE FUNCTION asf_ConvertANSIToUnicode (@Source varchar(500)) RETURNS nvarchar(500) AS
BEGIN
DECLARE @Result nvarchar(500)
DECLARE @i bigint
DECLARE @CharCode bigint
DECLARE @Diff bigint
SET @i = 1
SET @Result = ''
While @i <= LEN(@Source)
      Begin
        SET @CharCode = ASCII(SUBSTRING(@Source,@i,1))
        IF @CharCode<128
           SET @CharCode = @CharCode
        ELSE
            IF @CharCode between 178 and 253
                  begin
                        SET @Diff = @CharCode - 178
                        IF @CharCode % 2 = 0
                           SET @CharCode = 1329 + @Diff / 2
                        ELSE
                           SET @CharCode = 1377 + (@Diff-1) / 2
                  END
            ELSE 
                  SET @CharCode = CASE @CharCode
                                        When 162 Then 1415
                                        When 163 Then 1417
                                        When 164 Then 41
                                        When 165 Then 40
                                        When 166 Then 187
                                        When 167 Then 171
                                        When 168 Then 8212
                                        When 169 Then 46
                                        When 170 Then 1373
                                        When 171 Then 44
                                        When 172 Then 45
                                        When 173 Then 1418
                                        When 174 Then 8230
                                        When 175 Then 1372
                                        When 176 Then 1371
                                        When 177 Then 1374
                                        When 254 Then 1370
                                        ELSE @CharCode
                                   END
        SET @Result = @Result + nchar(@CharCode)
        SET  @i = @i + 1
      END 
RETURN @Result
END
```

So, I'm just use it and get data with unicode charset this way:

```
\DB::connection('sqlsrv')->select('SELECT test.dbo.asf_ConvertANSIToUnicode(a.MTNAME) 
    FROM test.dbo.VMATERIALS a;');
```

In my database setting I'm used this configuration:

```
'sqlsrv' => [
            'driver' => 'sqlsrv',
            'host' => env('MS_DB_HOST', 'localhost'),
            'port' => env('MS_DB_PORT', '1433'),
            'database' => env('MS_DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
            'username' => env('MS_DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
            'password' => env('MS_DB_PASSWORD', ''),
            'charset' => 'utf8',
            'prefix' => '',
        ],
```

Thanks to all.